# Attributes in django form model

Tags: python, django

hi i have django form model and i to want add my custom class for it but still i getting error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

My django code:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactFormModel
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'phoneNumber',
                  'message',)

        widgets = {
            'name': CharField(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        }
```

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CharField` is not a widget however [TextInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput) is!

```
widgets = {
    'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
}
```